# Create a mudlog (vertical line graph) with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a vertical graph of a dataset.

The idea is to have a negative y-axis which shows the position of the data, and multiple vertical lines that show dependent variable on the x axis as lines graphs to compare multiple samples.

Link to picture: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mud_logging#/media/File:Mud_Log_cDExp1.jpg

```
structure(list(feet = c(-0.3, -0.7, -1, -1.3, -1.6, -2, -2.3, 
-2.6, -3, -3.3, -3.6, -3.9, -4.3, -4.6, -4.9, -5.2, -5.6, -5.9, 
-6.2, -6.5, -6.6, -6.9, -7.2, -7.5, -7.9, -8, -8.2, -8.5, -8.9, 
-9.2, -9.3, NA), A.26 = c(7.23, 4.15, 4.95, 4.78, 5.83, 6.55, 
6.55, 6.19, 6.47, 6.01, 6.34, 6.51, 6.49, 6.33, 6.33, 2.98, 9.05, 
7.3, 7.91, NA, 7.93, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), A.33 = c(1.38, 4.95, 5.25, 5.24, 5.46, 5.32, 5.45, 5.72, 
5.38, 5.49, 5.57, 5.61, 5.61, 5.24, 5.38, 5.32, 5.45, 5.42, 5.25, 
NA, 5.36, 5.56, 5.68, 5.3, 5.46, NA, NA, 4.02, NA, NA, 3.85, 
NA), B.27 = c(1.53, 4.95, 5.53, 5.51, 6.48, 6.35, 6, 6.43, 6.2, 
6.14, 5.97, 5.79, 5.83, 5.69, 5.82, 6.19, 6.34, 7.77, 7.64, 7.66, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), B.28 = c(14, 
9.79, 11.45, 12.81, 14.07, 14.52, 14.92, 14.43, 9.09, 8.96, 7.56, 
0, 2.89, 5.02, 4.73, 5.16, 5.23, 6.41, 6.66, NA, 6.11, 6.92, 
7.49, 7.67, 6.98, 7.47, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("feet", 
"A.26", "A.33", "B.27", "B.28"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not even gonna try to parse that data you have... but here's an example of a time series that is vertical.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(time=c(1:100,1:100), 
                 y = c(rnorm(100, 4, 5), 
                       rnorm(100, 5, 2)), 
                 something=c(rep("AAAA", 100), rep("BBBB", 100)))
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=time, y=y, colour=something)) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I added the dput structure.. it has been a 18 months since using R so I forgot some of the basics.